# I'm trying to replace a character in Python while iterating over a string and but it doesn't work

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

This is the code I currently have:

```
letter = raw_input("Replace letter?")
traversed = raw_input("Traverse in?")
replacewith = raw_input("Replace with?")
traverseint = 0
for i in traversed:
    traverseint = traverseint + 1
    if i == letter:
        traversed[traverseint] = replacewith
        print i
print(traversed)
```

Comment: Ok and? You haven't shown anything except for your code. Questions asking "why doesn't my code work" are off-topic. You should consider editing your question to show desired output, and actual output, show where you're stuck, etc.

Answer (score 5):

[`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) in python are immutable by nature. That means, you can not modify the existing object. For example:

```
>>> 'HEllo'[3] = 'o'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

In order to replace the character in the string, ideal way is to use `str.replace()` method. For example:

```
>>> 'HEllo'.replace('l', 'o')
'HEooo'
```

---

Without using `str.replace()`, you may make your program run by using a temporary string as:

```
my_str = ''  # Temporary string

for i in traversed:
    # traverseint = traverseint + 1      # Not required
    if i == letter:
        i = replacewith
    my_str += i
```

Here `my_str` will hold the value of transformed `traversed`. OR, even better way to do this is by transforming the string to `list` (as mentioned by @chepner), update the values of list and finally join the `list` to get back the string. For example:

```
traversed_list = list(traversed)

for i, val in enumerate(traversed_list):
    if val == letter:
        traversed_list[i] = replacewith
        print i

my_str = ''.join(traversed_list)
```

Comment: A better approach is to add either `i` or `replacewith` to a list (which is mutable), then call `my_str = ''.join(new_list)` once the loop completes, to avoid creating new string objects every time you use `+=`.

Comment: Perhaps also point the OP to the powerful feature of the language comprehension/generators: `''.join(i if i != replacewith else replacewith for i in traversed)`

Answer (score 2):

I can not comment yet, but want add a bit to Moinuddin Quadri answer.

If index of replacement is not required, [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) should be a best solution.
If replacement index is required, just use [str.index()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) or str.find() for determine an replacement index, then use slice (see table) to "cut" ends and sum replacement between begin and end, or just call str.replace().

```
while True:
    index = traversed.find(letter)
    if index < 0:
        break
    print index
    traversed = traversed[:index] + replacewith + traversed[index + len(letter):]
    #or
    traversed = traversed.replace(letter, replacewith, 1)
```

Str is immutable, so direct slice assignment is not possible.
If you want directly modify a string, you should use a mutable type, like `bytearray`.

To check if string contains a substring you can use `in`

```
letter in traversed
```

"System" does not allow me to post more than 2 links. But all methods I have mentioned are on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify containers you are iterating over. And you cant edit strings by position.

Make a copy of the string first and make it a list object

```
letter = raw_input("Replace letter?")
traversed = raw_input("Traverse in?")
modify = list(traversed)
replacewith = raw_input("Replace with?")
for traverseint,i in enumerate(modify): 
    if i == letter:
        modify[traverseint] = replacewith
        print i 
print(''.join(modify))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create empty string and add letters (python 3.5)

```
letter = input("Replace letter?")
traversed = input("Traverse in?")
replacewith = input("Replace with?")
temp = ''
for i in traversed:
    if i == letter:
        temp += replacewith
    else:
        temp += i

print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also define own replace like below:

```
def replace(str, idx, char):
    if -1 < idx < len(str):
        return '{str_before_idx}{char}{str_after_idx}'.format(
            str_before_idx=str[0:idx], 
            char=char,
            str_after_idx=str[idx+1:len(str)]
        )
    else:
        raise IndexError
```

Where `str` is string to be manipulated, `idx` is an index, `char` is character to be replaced at index `idx`.